# Getting END_MISS notification when my Job Status - WAITING state

Tags: oozie-coordinator

I have set sla-nominal time as `${coord:nominalTime()}`, so my sla starts calculating taking coordinator triggering time as the start time for sla calculations.

But the problem is I have many workflows running on my cluster and my workflow goes to waiting state if no memory on the cluster.

eg: for a particular workflow my coordinator start time is 2.00 pm but due to memory issue it goes to waiting state and workflow get triggered at say 5 pm, and if my sla duration is 2 hrs. this condition is already crossed so I get end_miss notification when my job is in still waiting state.

So is there any way I can give actual workflow triggering time as sla nominal time instead of coordinator nominal-time. so that sla starts calculating when my process actually started running and not when in waiting state.